# Nginx shows html code

Tags: html, nginx

I have a domain with a single index.html
This are the settings for my Nginx server + php5-fpm

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/ecuation/fussball/app/;
    index index.html;

    server_name fussball.*******.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
            root html;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.html;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But when I browse the url It shows me the HTML code, it doenst execute it.
What could it be ?